# Uploading an 64base image to cloudinary using Nodejs and React Native

Tags: node.js, base64, react-native, cloudinary

I am trying to upload a 64 base image to cloudinary, i got an 'internal server error'.
How can I change this code to except uploading 64base image(I have tried to upload an image file and it did work)

Here is my Nodejs code:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(`data:image/png;base64,${req.body.image}`,
        function (error, result) { console.log(result, error); });
});
```

my react native code:

```
export const uploadCloud = ({image}) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        debugger;
        axios
            .post('https://randomApI.com/api/cloudinary', {image})
            .then(() => {
                dispatch({
                    type: UPLOAD_CLOUD,
                    payload: {image}
                });
            })
            .catch(err => err);
    };
};
```

If it is not clear for you, please ask for clarifications.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add console.log to get log crash from API? I want to see log

Comment: I have solved the problem . I have changed my Nodejs code like it is shown above. Thank you so much for trying to help